# MVC Bundle JS with Config from CDN

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, mathjax

Am trying to bundle a JS file that has a configuration in MVC 4,

http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?**config**=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML

BundleConfig.cs File,

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MathJax").Include(
       "~/Scripts/MathJax/MathJax.jsMathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"));
```

_Layout.chtml file

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MathJax")
```

When I include the JS in the header it works but does not work when included in the Bundle.

I tried to add the config to the render section,

BundleConfig.cs File,

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MathJax").Include(
       "~/Scripts/MathJax/MathJax.jsMathJax.js"));
```

_Layout.chtml file

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MathJax?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML")
```

Comment: Have you tried using the cdn parameter? `bundles.UseCdn = true; bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/virtual", "http://cdn...").Include("~/local"))`

Comment: I wanted to use a static library and avoid the content delivery network overload.

Comment: every find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

MathJax has many dependencies and doesn't seem to support bundling. It would require numerous changes to the js files themselves and would be unsupportable.

So the answer to your question is. **No, you cannot bundle Mathjax.**

Comment: I ended up using katex (https://katex.org/). It's currently only a release candidate, but works for my needs